# phpStorm remote debug goes to server_ip/index page all the time, what is wrong?

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I am trying to setup remote debug in a remote project under phpStorm 10.0.2 and I can't. Any time I set a breakpoints and hit `Shift+F9` or `Alt+Shift+F9` browser opens this URL: `http://remote_host_ip/index.php` and I don't know why. xDebug is installed and enabled, see the pic below for further info:

[image]

Debugger config seems to be fine, see the pic below:

[image]

What I am missing here?

---

The issue was "fixed" with **@lazyone** suggestion. Now I didn't get redirect to `http://remote_host_ip/index.php` but I am running in a second issue since breakpoints aren't respected. In the pic below I show my setup for `index.php` debug:

[image]

As soon as I start debug I can step into or step over but in none I get redirected to web page where I enter for example login and password. I am still missing something here just don't know what, any advice?

*Note:* Yes I know you will ask for all the configs I had made but are a bunch, so ask for them and I will edit the post to add them.

Comment: *"browser opens this URL: `http://remote_host_ip/index.php`"* -- check your existing Run/Debug configurations -- you must be calling currently active one (either via drop-down box on main toolbar (next to Run & Debug buttons) or via `Run | Edit Configurations...`. You will either need to choose another Run/Debug Configuration entry or create and use your own.

Comment: @LazyOne take a look to my latest edit and thanks for your help

Comment: You are using "PHP Script" type of configuration -- it is for executing scripts in CLI environment. Have a look at these manuals (in case if you have not seen them yet): https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm -- Zero config one in particular

Comment: @LazyOne I have followed every step on that guide you recommend me but I can't get this working yet. First debugger on the toolbar (the bookmark) seems to doing nothing, the extension installed in chrome has the same effect nothing, I can't see any incoming connection from XDebug, can we chat about this or are you to busy for this?

Comment: Extension and bookmarklet just sets the xdebug cookie .. so the next request sent to the page will have xdebug cookie set (enabled) which tells xdebug that this request must be debugged.  You already have `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` in your php.ini (which means that xdebug will attempt to debug every single request automatically) and therefore you don't really need for extension or bookmarklet.

Comment: @LazyOne even having that isn't working any ideas?

Comment: I suggest collecting xdebug log for such unsuccessful debug attempt -- it may tell what is going on (if xdebug is able to connect (firewall?); what IP:port it uses; script that will be debugged (wrong path/missing path mapping?) etc.

Comment: 1) is it local or remote (VM)? 2) Web server used? PHP version and how PHP is run (FastCGI/php-fpm etc) 3) Maybe worth upgrading xdebug to latest stable (2.3.x) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98859/discussion-between-reynierpm-and-lazyone).